# i have encountered some issues while using Stable Diffusion. It generates some strange limbs for me

Tags: training

My generation method involves using the original image along with SAM to extract masks for the images. Then I use OpenPose to fix the pose of the person and keep the clothes unchanged while generating different individuals.

However, the generated limbs are appearing strangely. Does anyone have a solution or any suggestions for improvement? Thank you, everyone.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try adding to the prompt "perfect fingers", "beautiful hands", (etc.) and to the negative prompt the opposite, "missing fingers", "deformed fingers", etc.